# Formula to display a result based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet which with 3 columns:

```
Column A: Start Date
Column B: Customer Name
Column C: Cost
```

At the moment I use a formula which allows me to enter a start date and end date and pulls out the total sum of all costs in that date range.

For example:

```
Start Date: 1/11/13
End Date: 22/11/13
```

A cost is displayed for all costs entered in that period.

The Formula Is:

```
=SUMIFS($C$7:$C$99997,$A$7:$A$99997,">="&$N$3,$A$7:$A$99997,"<="&$N$4)
```

I want to be able to **filter my results based on the customer name entered**. So if choose customer ABC from a drop down list, then the costs displayed will be changed to reflect this.

Comment: Just add another condition to the sumifs.  `=SUMIFS($C$7:$C$99997,$A$7:$A$99997,">="&$N$3,$A$7:$A$99997,"<="&$N$4,B$7:B$99997,"bob")` where bob could be stored in a cell next to it

Answer (score 0):

As per @gtwebb in a Comment:

> Just add another condition to the SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS($C$7:$C$99997,$A$7:$A$99997,">="&$N$3,$A$7:$A$99997,"<="&$N$4,B$7:B$999‌​97,"bob")
```

> where `bob` could be stored in a cell next to it.